# Meaning of 殴り描き and the use of 'would'

Tags: tense, japanese-to-english, neologism

I think I get most of this tweet

https://twitter.com/hanjuku_monme/status/1544706459556265985

> 今日（昨日）からメイドインアビス2期が始まると知ったのでファプタ殴り描き

"I knew that the second season of Made in Abyss would begin from yesterday, so today I (hit-drew?) Faputa"

What does '殴り描き' mean?

Also, is having a [present tense verb]+と+[past tense verb the] equivalent of adding a 'would' (as in talking about the future from the past) in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This word is probably mostly used as Internet slang and anime-niched Japanese. The meaning of the sentence is something along the lines of

> Because I heard they were going to release メイドインアビス's second season today, I dashed off a drawing of ファプタ

Note that the temporal adverbial 今日から connects with and modifies 始まる, so it's about when the new anime season will start airing. Yes, you could say "they would release" too, talking about something happening in the future from a point in the past.

殴り描き is a word used to describe drawings and sketches that are done in haste. Similar words include 殴り書き (scribbling, to scribble), 書き散らす, 書き散らし (also scribbling, to scribble). The 殴り part is just a metaphorical way to describe the messiness and carelessness with which the drawings or writing are done, so messy that it is almost violent. This is actually an example of 謙遜表現 and almost always used by the author themself to show their modesty. "My drawings are badly done." It's like how people always say, 字が汚い when they show their handwriting. See:

> 乱雑にがしぐしと描き殴ったイラスト。 概ね、投稿者の謙遜によるタグである。([source](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E6%AE%B4%E3%82%8A%E6%8F%8F%E3%81%8D))

> 殴るかのように乱暴に字を書く、乱雑に書く、といった意味の表現。([source](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%AE%B4%E3%82%8A%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D))

Comment: Are 謙遜語 and 謙譲語 the same thing?

Comment: @SpikedHelmet 謙譲語 is one of the defined categories of 敬語 and 謙遜語 can mean the same thing in the 敬語 system. For example [this dictionary definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%AC%99%E9%81%9C%E8%AA%9E/) only points 謙遜語 to 謙譲語. But I don't mean it like that. My use here is loose and refers to language that shows humility in a much broader sense.